# How to deploy to existing powerBI workspace?

Tags: powerbi, devops, continuous-deployment, powerbi-embedded, cicd

I am trying to implement a powerBI [deployment pipeline](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/power-bi/create-reports/deployment-pipelines-overview) . I already have workspaces created for each environment (Dev, test, prod). But while creating deployment pipeline, I can only assign one workspace. During deployment, pipeline itself creating new workspaces. Is there a way to use my existing workspaces for all environments instead of creating new one?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is now possible to do so - https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/power-bi/create-reports/deployment-pipelines-assign#assign-a-workspace-to-any-vacant-pipeline-stage

Answer (score 0):

That's not possible. You have to use the pipeline's **Deploy** function to copy content from one stage to another. Even if you publish your Test and Prod contents directly to the according pipeline stages and use the exacly same names, Power BI won't recognize the relations between them and you can't use the **Compare** function to keep track of your developments.