# How to allocate already present Dev, Test and Prod workspaces to a Power BI Deployment Pipeline?

Tags: powerbi, continuous-deployment, powerbi-embedded, powerbi-datasource, cicd

I am trying to create a Power BI Deployment Pipeline for my already existing Dev, Test and Prod workspaces which reside on a Premium Capacity with a diamond symbol next to them. I am only able to assign any one of the workspaces and the other two workspaces get freshly created and I cannot point them manually to the existing workspaces. Is there any way to achieve this?

Comment: This question is an exact duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69046642/how-to-deploy-to-existing-powerbi-workspace

Answer (score 0):

That's not possible. You have to use the pipeline's **Deploy** function to copy reports and datasets from one stage to another. Even if you publish your Test and Prod reports/datasets directly to the according pipeline stages and use the exactly same names, Power BI won't recognize the relations between them and you can't use the **Compare** function to keep track of your developments.

Answer (score 0):

The ability to add workspaces to all stages will be available soon- https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/power-platform-release-plan/2021wave1/power-bi/deployment-pipelines--assign-workspace-all-pipeline-stages

Answer (score 0):

You can now assign any workspace to any stage in pipeline:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/power-bi/create-reports/deployment-pipelines-assign#assign-a-workspace-to-any-vacant-pipeline-stage