# How to add 'UAT' stage in PowerBI deployment pipeline?

Tags: powerbi, continuous-deployment, powerbi-embedded, cicd

When I create new deployment pipeline in PowerBI, it shows 3 stages (Development -> Test -> Production) by default. Is there a way to add new stage to pipeline like UAT (Development -> Test -> UAT -> Production)?

Edit#1
[error while patching credentials-Andrey](https://i.stack.imgur.com/er4Nm.png)

Comment: As I know there is no way to add next stage:

(this is also true for API; The deployment pipeline stage order. Development (0), Test (1), Production (2).) more info:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/power-bi/pipelines/get-pipeline-stage-artifacts

Answer (score 0):

No, it is not possible. As clearly written in the [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/power-bi/create-reports/deployment-pipelines-overview), Power BI Deployment Pipelines has only three stages:

> The tool is designed as a pipeline **with three stages**:
>
> - **Development**
>
> This stage is used to design, build, and upload new content with fellow creators. This is the first stage in deployment pipelines.
>
> - **Test**
>
> You're ready to enter the test stage after you've made all the needed changes to your content. You upload the modified content so it can be moved to this test stage. Here are three examples of what can be done in the test environment:
>
> - Share content with testers and reviewers
> - Load and run tests with larger volumes of data
> - Test your app to see how it will look for your end users
> - **Production**
>
> After testing the content, use the production stage to share the final version of your content with business users across the organization.

But the names and the purpose of these three stages doesn't necessary means that you have to use them this way. You can test in stage 0 (a.k.a. Development) and use stage 1 (a.k.a. Test) as UAT, or repurpose Production stage for that. You can always use the API to automate the missing stage by copying and deploying the artifacts on your own. For example, here is a PowerShell script, which will copy all reports from one workspace to another, change their datasource and patch the credentials. The example uses SQL Server, but you can extend it to support other types if needed. Also, if there are datasets with multiple datasources, you will have to loop through them too.

```
Import-Module MicrosoftPowerBIMgmt

# Get from Azure AD -> Properties (https://portal.azure.com/#blade/Microsoft_AAD_IAM/ActiveDirectoryMenuBlade/Properties)
$tenantId = "xxxxxxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxxxxxxxxxx"
# Get Application (client) ID from Azure AD -> App registrations (https://portal.azure.com/#blade/Microsoft_AAD_IAM/ActiveDirectoryMenuBlade/RegisteredApps)
$applictionId = "xxxxxxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxxxxxxxxxx"
# Create it from application's "Certificates & secrets" section
$applicationSecret = "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx"
# The name of the workspace from which you will take all reports
$fromWorkspaceName = "Dev workspace"
# The name of the workspace where the reports will be copied
$toWorkspaceName = "Test workspace"

# Information about the datasources used
$fromServerName = "dev.database.windows.net"
$fromDatabaseName = "Sales"
$toServerName = "test.database.windows.net"
$toDatabaseName = "Sales"
$sqlUserName = "sa"
$sqlUserPassword = "P@ssw0rd"

# Functions

function DownloadReport
{
    Write-Host "Downloading $($fromReport.Name) from $($fromWorkspace.Name)..."
    $tempFolder = [System.IO.Path]::GetTempPath()
    $subFolder = [System.Guid]::NewGuid()
    $workingFolder = New-Item -ItemType Directory -Path (Join-Path $tempFolder $subFolder)
    $tempFile = Join-Path $workingFolder ([System.Guid]::NewGuid().ToString() + ".pbix")
    try
    {
        Export-PowerBIReport -WorkspaceId $fromWorkspace.Id -Id $fromReport.Id -OutFile $tempFile
        return $tempFile    
    }
    catch
    {
        Resolve-PowerBIError -Last
    }
}

function UploadReport
{
    param(
        [Parameter(Mandatory=$true)]
        [ValidateNotNullOrEmpty()]
        [String]$FileToUpload
    )
    Write-Host "Uploading $($fromReport.Name) to $($toWorkspace.Name)..."
    try
    {
        $report = New-PowerBIReport -Path $fileToUpload -Name $fromReport.Name -Workspace $toWorkspace -ConflictAction CreateOrOverwrite
        return $report
    }
    catch
    {
        Resolve-PowerBIError -Last
    }
}

function GetDataset
{
    param(
        [Parameter(Mandatory=$true)]
        [ValidateNotNullOrEmpty()]
        [Microsoft.PowerBI.Common.Api.Reports.Report]$Report
    )
    Write-Host "Finding the dataset..."
    if ($Report.DatasetId -ne $null) # Do we know the dataset Id?
    {
        # Get the dataset by Id
        $dataset = Get-PowerBIDataset -WorkspaceId $toWorkspace.Id -Id $Report.DatasetId
    }
    else
    {
        # Get the dataset by the name of the report
        $dataset = Get-PowerBIDataset -WorkspaceId $toWorkspace.Id -Name $Report.Name
    }
    return $dataset
}

function ChangeDataSource
{
    param(
        [Parameter(Mandatory=$true)]
        [ValidateNotNullOrEmpty()]
        [Microsoft.PowerBI.Common.Api.Datasets.Dataset]$Dataset
    )

    Write-Host "Checking the datasource..."

    # Construct url
    $datasetBaseUrl = "groups/$($toWorkspace.Id)/datasets/$($Dataset.Id)"
    $datasourceUrl = "$datasetBaseUrl/datasources"
    $datasourePatchUrl = "$datasetBaseUrl/Default.UpdateDatasources"

    # Call the REST API to get gateway Id, datasource Id and current connection details
    $datasourcesResult = Invoke-PowerBIRestMethod -Method Get -Url $datasourceUrl | ConvertFrom-Json

    # Parse the response
    $datasource = $datasourcesResult.value[0] # If your report has many, loop through them
    $gatewayId = $datasource.gatewayId
    $datasourceId = $datasource.datasourceId
    $sqlDatabaseServerCurrent = $datasource.connectionDetails.server
    $sqlDatabaseNameCurrent = $datasource.connectionDetails.database

    if (($sqlDatabaseServerCurrent -ieq $fromServerName) -and ($sqlDatabaseNameCurrent -ieq $fromDatabaseName))
    {
        Write-Host "Updating the datasource..."
        # create HTTP request body to update datasource connection details
        $postBody = @{
          "updateDetails" = @(
           @{
            "connectionDetails" = @{
              "server" = "$toServerName"
              "database" = "$toDatabaseName"
            }
            "datasourceSelector" = @{
              "datasourceType" = "Sql"
              "connectionDetails" = @{
                "server" = "$sqlDatabaseServerCurrent"
                "database" = "$sqlDatabaseNameCurrent"
              }
              "gatewayId" = "$gatewayId"
              "datasourceId" = "$datasourceId"
            }
          })
        }

        $postBodyJson = ConvertTo-Json -InputObject $postBody -Depth 6 -Compress

        try
        {
            # Execute POST operation to update datasource connection details
            Invoke-PowerBIRestMethod -Method Post -Url $datasourePatchUrl -Body $postBodyJson
            return $true
        }
        catch
        {
            Resolve-PowerBIError -Last
        }
        return $false
    }
}

function PatchCredentials
{
    param(
        [Parameter(Mandatory=$true)]
        [ValidateNotNullOrEmpty()]
        [Microsoft.PowerBI.Common.Api.Datasets.Dataset]$Dataset
    )
    
    Write-Host "Patching the credentials..."

    # Construct url
    $datasetBaseUrl = "groups/$($toWorkspace.Id)/datasets/$($Dataset.Id)"
    $datasourceUrl = "$datasetBaseUrl/datasources"
    $datasourePatchUrl = "$datasetBaseUrl/Default.UpdateDatasources"

    # Call the REST API to get gateway Id, datasource Id and current connection details
    $datasourcesResult = Invoke-PowerBIRestMethod -Method Get -Url $datasourceUrl | ConvertFrom-Json

    # Parse the response
    $datasource = $datasourcesResult.value[0] # If your report has many, loop through them

    $gatewayId = $datasource.gatewayId
    $datasourceId = $datasource.datasourceId
    $datasourePatchUrl = "gateways/$gatewayId/datasources/$datasourceId"

    # HTTP request body to patch datasource credentials
    $userNameJson = "{""name"":""username"",""value"":""$sqlUserName""}"
    $passwordJson = "{""name"":""password"",""value"":""$sqlUserPassword""}"

    $patchBody = @{
    "credentialDetails" = @{
        "credentials" = "{""credentialData"":[ $userNameJson, $passwordJson ]}"
        "credentialType" = "Basic"
        "encryptedConnection" =  "NotEncrypted"
        "encryptionAlgorithm" = "None"
        "privacyLevel" = "Organizational"
    }
    }

    # Convert body contents to JSON
    $patchBodyJson = ConvertTo-Json -InputObject $patchBody -Depth 6 -Compress

    # Execute PATCH operation to set datasource credentials
    Invoke-PowerBIRestMethod -Method Patch -Url $datasourePatchUrl -Body $patchBodyJson    
}

function RefreshDataset
{
    param(
        [Parameter(Mandatory=$true)]
        [ValidateNotNullOrEmpty()]
        [Microsoft.PowerBI.Common.Api.Datasets.Dataset]$Dataset
    )
    
    Write-Host "Refreshing the report..."

    # Construct url
    $datasetRefreshUrl = "groups/$($toWorkspace.Id)/datasets/$($Dataset.Id)/refreshes"

    # We will skip the request body (notifyOption), so it will give us "WARNING: The Body parameter was null, the request may be invalid when Method parameter is Post."
    Invoke-PowerBIRestMethod -Method Post -Url $datasetRefreshUrl -WarningAction SilentlyContinue
}

function Cleanup
{
    param(
        [Parameter(Mandatory=$true)]
        [ValidateNotNullOrEmpty()]
        [String]$FileToDelete
    )
    $folderToDelete = Split-Path -Path $FileToDelete
    Remove-Item -Path $FolderToDelete -Recurse
}

# Login into Power BI Service
$SecuredApplicationSecret = ConvertTo-SecureString -String $applicationSecret -AsPlainText -Force
$credential = New-Object System.Management.Automation.PSCredential($applictionId, $SecuredApplicationSecret)
$sp = Connect-PowerBIServiceAccount -ServicePrincipal -Tenant $tenantId -Credential $credential
# Write-Host "Logged in as: $($sp.UserName), $($sp.LoginType)"

# Find source and target workspaces
$fromWorkspace = Get-PowerBIWorkspace -Name $fromWorkspaceName
$toWorkspace = Get-PowerBIWorkspace -Name $toWorkspaceName
#$fromWorkspace = Get-PowerBIWorkspace -Id $fromWorkspaceId
#$toWorkspace = Get-PowerBIWorkspace -Id $toWorkspaceId

# Get all reports in the source workspace and loop though them
$allReports = Get-PowerBIReport -WorkspaceId $fromWorkspace.Id
foreach ($fromReport in $allReports)
{
    $fileName = DownloadReport
    $newReport = UploadReport -FileToUpload $fileName
    $newDataset = GetDataset -Report $newReport
    if (ChangeDataSource -Dataset $newDataset)
    {
        PatchCredentials -Dataset $newDataset
        RefreshDataset -Dataset $newDataset
    }
    Cleanup -FileToDelete $fileName
}

# Be a nice guy and say goodbye
Disconnect-PowerBIServiceAccount
```

Comment: Does your script can be used as an alternative to powerBI deployment pipeline, if I want to deploy to existing workspaces?
Sorry for deviating from the context, but I have another question in pipeline, which I posted at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69046642/how-to-deploy-to-existing-powerbi-workspace

Comment: Yes, it can. But make sure you clearly understand how it works and what will be the effect when it runs. You may want to modify it to perform selective deployments based on some criteria of your choice.

Comment: Hi Andrey, Your script was super useful. I was able to update the datasource and patch its credentials. 
But when I run that script again, by deleting all datasets from 'toWorkspace', it gives another error in patching creds(screenshot attached in original question with edit#1).

Comment: Thank you, @AniketKarajgikar! I'm happy to help

Comment: Welcome! can you please check my updated comment>

Comment: Error 400 is most likely caused by invalid parameters, etc. It may depend on the datasource type and number of datasources in the dataset, etc. You will have to check these and make the necessary changes in the script.

Comment: @AndreyNikolov The script will not work for incremental and reports that are on large dataset. As the export functionality will not be available with such type of datasets.